# How to change soft input panel (SIP) to digits only?

Tags: windows-phone-7, soft-input-panel

I've use the "Digits" and "Numeric" input scopes on the emulator for windows phone7 but on the actual device it ends up being the default input scope.

How do I change it to "Numeric" on the actual device? Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: `Number` has become numbers-only on Mango devices. Is your device pre-mango?

Comment: @willmel, yes it's pre mango.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InputScope="TelephoneNumber" works on both Mango and NoDo.

Comment: If you're following my answer, there is no need to wait for Mango.  This works in Mango AND NoDo (NoDo is what most people have now).

Comment: I'll have to wait for the mango update to use the "Number" input scope, since it doesn't work on NoDo. In the mean time I'll use Telephone Number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code:

```
InputScope scope = new InputScope();
InputScopeName scopeName = new InputScopeName();
scopeName.NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.Number;
scope.Names.Add(scopeName);

tblInputField.Inputscope = scope;
```